# Normalisation of 1D FFT in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft, dft

I am trying to measure the power spectrum of Gaussian realisations, but I do not know how to fix the normalisation of the FFTs. In the current version, the measured power spectrum is dependent on the Nmesh I use. I want the normalisation to be valid not only for the Gaussian field but also for even powers of the field. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

norm_FFT = "ortho"

def MeasurePS(grid_abs_k, field, k_min, k_max, dk):
    """
    Function to measure the power spectrum
    """
    
    global norm_FFT
    
    #FFT of the input field
    _field_Fourier = np.fft.fft(field, norm = norm_FFT)*Normk
    
    #Compute the absolute value of the field in Fourier space
    _field_Fourier_abs = np.abs(_field_Fourier)**2
    
    #Generate the array that will be used to compute the power spectrum
    k_bins = np.arange(k_min, k_max + dk, dk)
    k_ctrs = 0.5*(k_bins[1:] + k_bins[:-1])
    
    #Generate the array to storage the power spectrum
    ps_output = np.zeros_like(k_ctrs)
    
    #Estimate the power spectrum
    for i in range(len(ps_output)):
        _ = _field_Fourier_abs
        mask_modes = (grid_abs_k > k_bins[i]) & (grid_abs_k <= k_bins[i+1])
        _ = _[mask_modes]
        ps_output[i] = np.average(_)
    return k_ctrs, ps_output


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize = (15,4))
for factor in [2**n for n in range(1,8)]:
    np.random.seed(1)

    #Input specs.
    Nmesh = 2**10*factor
    H = L/Nmesh #cell size (resolution)
    kf = 2*np.pi/L
    k_Ny = Nmesh*kf/2
    
    Normx = np.sqrt(Nmesh)
    Normk = 1.0/Normx

    #Compute the 1D momentum array
    k_array = np.fft.fftfreq(Nmesh)*2*np.pi/H
    grid_k_abs = np.sqrt(np.abs(k_array)**2)

    np.random.seed(1)
    gaussian_seed = np.random.normal(0,1,size=[Nmesh])
    
    #Take the fourier transform of the Gaussian seed
    gaussian_seed_fourier = np.fft.fft(gaussian_seed, norm = norm_FFT)*Normk

    #Compute the power Spectrum
    ps = linear_power(grid_k_abs,A,R)

    #Get the desired Gaussian field by multiplying the white-noise by sqrt(P(k))
    G_k = gaussian_seed_fourier*ps**0.5

    #Take the inverse transform
    G = np.fft.ifft(G_k, norm =  norm_FFT).real
    G *= Normx
    G2 = G**2 - np.mean(G**2)
    G4 = G**4 - np.mean(G**4)
    
    k, ps = MeasurePS(grid_k_abs,G, kf,k_Ny,70*kf)
    k, ps2 = MeasurePS(grid_k_abs,G2, kf,k_Ny,70*kf)
    k, ps4 = MeasurePS(grid_k_abs,G4, kf,k_Ny,70*kf)
    ax[0].plot(k,k*ps)
    ax[1].plot(k,k*ps2)
    ax[2].plot(k,k*ps4)
    
ax[0].set_xlim((0,15))
ax[0].set_xlabel("waveumber")
ax[0].set_title("Power spectrum of G")
ax[1].set_xlim((0,15))
ax[1].set_xlabel("waveumber")
ax[1].set_title("Power spectrum of $G^2$")
ax[2].set_xlim((0,15))
ax[2].set_title("Power spectrum of $G^4$")
ax[2].set_xlabel("waveumber")
```

I need to fix the normalisation in such a way that there is no dependence on the measured power spectrum on the Nmesh I use.